# Unable to connect to azure sql server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I created a new Azure Mobile App and set up my Sql Server database with it. I use an email address as the username, and then assigned a password.

Once the Mobile App and the Sql Server db setup completed, I was able to get my iOS app to target it and use the Azure authentication services without any issue. I then inserted some data in to a table in the iOS app, without any errors.

Now, I want to open the database and verify the data. Anytime I try to connect to the server using SSMS or Visual Studio 2015, I am told that the login failed.

I use an email address like Johnathon@MyCompany.com. When the sign-in fails, it says:

> Login failed for user 'Johnathon'.

Is it the email address for a login causing issues? My ISP blocks port 1433, so I thought that maybe that was the issue initially. So instead of using VS or SSMS, I moved to the web-designer on the Azure portal. When I sign in there, I receive the same error. This has occured across three different App Services setups. I tried using the older Mobile Services, and had this issue. I then moved to the newly released Mobile App Service but have the same issue. Each time I deleted the database and recreated it and the server.

I have also added my client IP to the azure sql server firewall.

I'm at a loss at this point.

#### Update

I have managed to sign in to the server within the Azure portal designer by omitting the database name. However, when I select the Design option, and then click the Design button on the database, I receive a `Failed to create context` error. I assume this is related to why I can't connect to the server when I specify a database name in the Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: What has Azure Technical Support told you?

Comment: I have not reached out to them. I just signed up for it for the first time this afternoon, so I'm still working my way around. I was hoping before I opened a ticket that maybe someone on here would know the answer.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-us/9e46c1d8-2d4d-41c2-8bf2-adace3a8bd24/failed-to-establish-connection-to-database?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that post. I will give it a shot once it is finished upgrading to V12.

Answer (score 1):

As a note, having the @ symbol in the SQL Azure login tends to cause a number of headaches and it is not recommended to have it in there. What you will notice is that SSMS and other applications try to use it as part of the server name which then causes context and other failures.

The easiest fix for this is to roll up another SQL Azure server with a login name that doesn't use the @ symbol, you will have a better experience overall.